# Track down disk activity MacMini and Mojave

Tags: hard-drive, mojave, fusion-drive

Late 2014 MacMini with combo SSD + HD Fusion Drive

Usually runs great, about 3x a day I can hear the HD really doing a lot of activity, reads / writes.

What can I use to determine which process is doing all of these reads / writes? I really want to find out what kind of diagnostics tool I can use to pinpoint what is doing all the reads / writes. I found some commands searching but those required booting into safe mode, I assume there is something I can use that doesn't require safe mode.

I can see from Activity Monitor that the IO spikes, but I cannot see a way to include a Read / sec column to activity monitor. Assume I need to use something else.

Image 1 shows high disk usage, image two shows it settling back down. 
For context on total IO:
Time since boot:    26 days 22:20

Thanks for the help.

[image: High IO]
[image: Normal IO]
[image]

Comment: FYI Added the backup after this problem started happening in case disk is failing or system fails. Still need to root cause it in case backup has the same issue.

Comment: You're not going to get individual *transfer rates* for each app - that's not the way it works.  That measurement is for the disk as a whole.  That said, what is it that you're looking for that Activity Monitor isn't presenting you?

Comment: I am trying to see which app is responsible for the increased IO. I understand I probably cannot use Activity Monitor, looking for alternatives or command line commands that work without booting into safe mode.

Comment: Activity monitor does in fact tell you which app is responsible for the most disk activity.  Reading is a lot less intensive than writing and both of those values are presented.

Comment: OK I am looking for a "what is writing to disk right now" metric. Or last 10 min. The data graph at the bottom is perfect but I want to see per app.

Comment: This is still going on, disk thrashes for about an hour two times a day. Really looking for a way to find out "What is writing 2MB/sec to disk right now"